# jquery 2.0 bundling minification conditional comments

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

With jQuery 2.0 Beta 2 being released meaning support for IE > 9 and other browsers how are people handling the bundling and minification for the various jquery versions. 
jQuery 1.9 = IE6-8
jQuery 2.0 = IE9 and other browsers

jQuery suggests to use this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="jquery-2.0.0b2.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

But what if you wanted to bundle jQuery, will you have to create 2 bundles one containing one version of jquery say v1.9 and one containing 2.0 and Use Rquest.BRowser?

DotnetShadow

Comment: Why do you want to use different jQuery versions for different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use different jQuery versions for different browsers?

Why not use 1.9 for all browsers?

Unless you have a very string reason to use two different versions, you'd be better off using just 1.9.x which is valid for newer and older browsers.

If you still want to use both versions, yes, you have to use two different bundles, and decide which one to render depending on the requesting browser.

However I still think it's safer to use the version which works for all version of browsers, even if the library is "a little less smart".

The only reason which could be in favor of using 2.x would be that 1.9.x hadn't support in the future, [but that's not the case](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, the only reason I would even consider this is for the smaller file size or if as you said they stopped supporting future browsers in 1.9.x